# Create Buttons and it's signals dynamically in Ruby GTK

Tags: ruby, gtk

i'm trying to make a Nurikabe puzzle with Ruby GTK and i'm having trouble creating button signals dynamically.
Basically, i have a matrix, some boxes have a number ( clicking them won't do anything), others can have one of 3 states (white, black or unplayed). The matrix can have different sizes so i did this :

```
def construction
    # we get the width and height of the matrix
    taille_hauteur = @@partie.grilleEnCours.hauteur
    taille_largeur = @@partie.grilleEnCours.largeur
    @boutons = {}
    #We create a table which will include all of our buttons (one for each box of our matrix)
    table = Table.new(taille_hauteur,taille_largeur,false)
    # we go through our matrix
    for i in 0..taille_largeur-1
        for j in 0..taille_hauteur-1
            # if the box has a number, we create a button with that number as a label
            if @@partie.grilleEnCours.matriceCases[i][j].is_a?(CaseNombre)
                # we add this button to a hash
                @boutons[[i,j]] = Button.new(:label=> @@partie.grilleEnCours.matriceCases[i][j].to_s)
                table.attach(@boutons[[i,j]], i, i+1, j, j+1)
            else
                # otherwise,we create and add a button to the hash without a label
                @boutons[[i,j]] = Button.new()
                # we create a signal, changing the state of the box of the matrix at the same coordinates as the button
                @boutons[[i,j]].signal_connect('clicked'){
                puts "#{i} #{j}"
                # we change the box's state of the matrix
                @@partie.clicSurCase(i,j)
                puts @@partie.grilleEnCours
                # here we are just changing the label corresponding to the box's state
                if(@@partie.grilleEnCours.matriceCases[i][j].etat==0)
                    lab = ""
                elsif (@@partie.grilleEnCours.matriceCases[i][j].etat==1)
                    lab = "Noir"
                else
                    lab = "Point"
                end
                @boutons[[i,j]].set_label(lab)
            }
                table.attach(@boutons[[i,j]], i, i+1, j, j+1)
            end
        end
    end
    @object.add(table)
end
```

The problem is, doing this, when we click any button, it will change the last box of the matrix and the last button's label (bottom right). I believe this is because Integers are objects in Ruby so clicking a button will change the box's state and button's state at the coordinates (i,j) (which are matrix height-1, matrix width-1) and not the values i and j had when we created the signal.

I have no idea how to link a button to a specific box of the matrix (knowing matrixes can have multiple sizes), could you help me on this one ?

Answer (score 0):

It is quite hard to read such a large block of code - maybe start by chopping it into logic-based functions?

It will clear the code up.
you don't need to set "lab =" in each branch of if - just:

```
lab = if (i==1)
1
else
2
end
```

in additions - use "case" in this case. Once you split the code up - you will(probably) find the issue you have.
it will be easier to debbug.